# Как привести к generic типу?

Tags: c#, рефлексия

```
private bool TryParseOf<TType>(string s, out TType result)
{
    if (typeof(TType) == typeof(int))
    {
        var parseSuccessful = int.TryParse(s, out var innerResult);
        result = innerResult; // в этой строке проблема
        return parseSuccessful;
    }
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

нельзя просто взять и привести. `TType` может быть `int`, `string`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private bool TryParseOf<TType>(string s, out TType result)
{
    var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(TType));
    try
    {
        result = (TType)converter.ConvertFromString(s);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        result = default;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Если делаем для простых типов, то

```
public class MyClass
{
    public bool TryParseOf<TType>(string s, out TType result)
    {
        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(TType));
        if (converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))
        {
            result = (TType)converter.ConvertFrom(s);
            return true;
        }
        result = default(TType);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Проверка

```
var c = new MyClass();  
if (c.TryParseOf("11", out int i)) Console.WriteLine(i); // 11
if (c.TryParseOf("11", out double j)) Console.WriteLine(j); // 11
```

Comment: кидает `ArgumentException` при "опечатках". я пофиксил обычным `try-catch`. можно ли сделать лучше?

Comment: я правкой поставлю свой вариант, ок?

Comment: @dgzargo ставьте, если это вам поможет с вашей задачей, я не против :)

Answer (score 3):

В принципе, приведение можно сделать через `object`, но я не уверен, будут ли там тогда лишняя упаковка и распаковка. Если будут, то способ мне не очень нравится.

https://ideone.com/ziADyJ

```
using System;

public class Test
{
  private static bool TryParseOf<TType>(string s, out TType result)
  {
    if (typeof(TType) == typeof(int))
    {
      var parseSuccessful = int.TryParse(s, out int innerResult);
      result = (TType)(object)innerResult;
      return parseSuccessful;
    }

    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  public static void Main()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", TryParseOf1<int>("123", out var x), x);
  }
}
```

Comment: это не универсальный вариант, но оно работает!

Comment: @dgzargo, а в чём неуниверсальность, если типы одинаковы?

Comment: думаю, да, тут и упаковка и распаковка.

Comment: @tym32167, jit может оптимизировать, но я не уверен.

Comment: вроде [есть и то и другое](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzOVp.png)

Comment: @tym32167, ты il-код показываешь - там само собой есть. Надо скомпилированный после jit'а смотреть.

Comment: а, ну это мне лень смотреть )

Comment: В .NET 5, да, убирает, вместе с проверкой типа. Вот упрощённый вариант: https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgAgJgIwFgBQcAMACAygCzACcAHAGTACMA6AJQFcA7YASygFMBuddOAZmyJsAFXYRg6AN7ps2ANoApFsADi7RuyIsAxgApgATxLsA9gDNdLZgEprAXRmCkANhHCj7bAAViEdgHkzAB5hd2MAPl04JBwIa0dpNFlZFjNsfQ9zXVCPa2wAXnzsQ2Msq2BbR1lE5OSAN2JsIjF6ABtgAuxy6h8iP1047iTawQB2dJzja10TSgArdm0K5og24CHagF8eYdlgfCITAHdsDROAORNgAEkoElb2DmZ2ABMAUQAPbXYSVhNGXTWDbYbZoTZAA=. Он заинлайнил int.Parse, и после него тупо возвращает результат как есть.

Comment: @VladD, круто :)